# SQL Server - Get first node from HierarchyId field

Tags: sql-server, hierarchical-data, hierarchyid

Suppose I have the following `HIERARCHYID` column in my SQL Server table:

```
MyCol   
/1/1/   
/2/1/   
/3/1/1/ 
/3/1/2/ 
/3/2/1/1/   
/3/2/1/2/   
/4/1/   
/4/2/   
/5/1/   
/6/1/   
/7/1/   
/8/1/   
/8/2/
```

And I want to write a query that returns the following `INT` `TopNode` column -
 basically returning the top-level value of the `MyCol` column:

```
MyCol       TopNode
/1/1/       1
/2/1/       2
/3/1/1/     3
/3/1/2/     3
/3/2/1/1/   3
/3/2/1/2/   3
/4/1/       4
/4/2/       4
/5/1/       5
/6/1/       6
/7/1/       7
/8/1/       8
/8/2/       8
```

I'm fairly new to using the HierarchyId data type and am having an issue finding the correct function between `GetDescendant`, `GetLevel` etc to be able to return this integer.

How can I accomplish this in the easiest way possible?

Comment: is it always a single digit for the top node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work in your case?

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(X HIERARCHYID)
INSERT @T SELECT '/1/1/'   
INSERT @T SELECT '/2/1/'   
INSERT @T SELECT '/3/1/'  
INSERT @T SELECT '/3/2/'   
INSERT @T SELECT '/3/3/'   
INSERT @T SELECT '/3/4/'

SELECT 
    X.GetAncestor(X.GetLevel()-1),
    X.GetAncestor(X.GetLevel()-1).ToString()  
FROM @T
```

You can then derive the int by casting from a simple replace -->

```
TopLevel = CAST(REPLACE(X.GetAncestor(X.GetLevel()-1).ToString(),'/','') AS INT)
```

Comment: I added a cast to int for TopLevel.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood your answer - It's perfect!!!
*THANK YOU*

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(YourString, CHARINDEX('/', YourString) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', YourString,CHARINDEX('/', YourString)+1) - (CHARINDEX('/', YourString) + 1))
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! - I was **HOPING** there was a way to deal with it directly as a `HIERARCHYID` field, but that'll definitely do the trick!!